# Minecraft redstone circuit turns off all other circuits after any of them are turned on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What I'm trying to do is to get the momentary switches to activate the paths on the left of the RS NOR latches and when you activate one it deactivates all the other activated switches. The idea is basically for one switch to deactivate all the other switches. I need as compact a design that allows for easy extensibility (adding more switches as need be)

(I will be adding a circuit pattern on the right side of the RS NOR as well but wanted to get it working this way for now.)

My understanding is that I need to only switch the top switch if it's not activated locally and the reset circuit is fired...I've tried the not/and path from the switch and from the activated line and neither ever works.

I've tried the following test and have been playing with it all morning. Any thoughts?

[image: Sample minecraft circuit]

### Update

I've been playing around with this some more and I think I'm on the right track...however the right circuit doesn't want to travel all the way around and if I add one more *not* then the top is an endless loop...which will turn off the most recently activated circuit once you stop off the stone button

[image: Test two]

Comment: What is the purpose of the redstone torch on the block a couple blocks left and down from each RS-NOR latch - is it just an indicator for the player?

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to indicate which button was pressed or is active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating answer with much more compact version

[image: More compact version]

#### Old stuff

I hate answering my own question but I found the answer here: http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=60816 (I was searching google for a switch diagram when I found it via station selection search since it seems most people use it for minecart stations)

Here is the schematic for anyone interested in reproducing it. This particular one is great because it's only one button wide which makes it perfect for my goal. [image: Single wide schematic]

Here's another one that has the indicator lights on the same plane as the button but I haven't checked this one to see how it performs. [image: Single wide schematic]

Comment: Nothing wrong in answering your own question - assuming the answer is *right*, of course. :)

Comment: Of course, I still don't like it (I'm not new to stackexchange but just this section.)

Comment: It's perfectly normal on stackexchange to answer one's own question.

Comment: how do you make those pictures